# I need help getting my footer to not cover my content when I resize the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used this [Sticky Footer](https://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) solution to get my footer to stick to the bottom of my page even when the browser is resized. 
Here is my html and internal css.

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
/*  
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher 
http://stever.ca
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/

* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#header {
top:-14px;
left:-20px;
background-image:url('header.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 140%;
background-position:-344px;
height:333px !important;
width:1349px;
}

#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {
position:relative;
background-image: url('footerbg.jpg');
margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 180px;
width:1349px;
clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}


ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}



a:link{text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

a:link    {color:white !important;
-webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-in;  
-moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-in;  
-o-transition:color 0.3s ease-in;  
transition:color 0.3s ease-in;  
}
a:visited {color:white !important;}
a:hover   {color:red !important;}
a:active  {color:white !important;}


#news{
position:relative;
top:300px;
left:195px;
height: 20px;
width: 30px;
}

#shop{
position:relative;
top:280px;
left:665px;
height: 20px;
width: 30px;
}


#coming{
position:relative;
top:390px;
left:15px;
color: #000000 !important;
}

a.maillink {color:blue !important;}
a.maillink:hover {color:pink;text-decoration:none !important;}




nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none !important; }
nav li {
float: left; }



#nav1 { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:34.5%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:white;
font-size:.9em;

z-index:1;
}


#nav2 { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:36.3%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:white;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}


#nav3 { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:38%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:white;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}

#nav4 { 
 position:relative;
 top:11px;
 left:39.8%;
 font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
 color:white;
 font-size:.9em;
 z-index:1;
 }


#nav5 { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:41.6%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:white;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}


#nav1:hover { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:34.5%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:red;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}


#nav2:hover { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:36.3%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:red;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}


#nav3:hover { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:38%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:red;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}

#nav4:hover { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:39.8%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:red;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}


#nav5:hover { 
position:relative;
top:11px;
left:41.6%;
font-family: insolentitalic, insolentregular;
color:red;
font-size:.9em;
z-index:1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li id="nav1"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="">ETC</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="">ETC</a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="">ETC</a></li>
    <li id="nav5"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="main">
<p>My main content here</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is what I have now:
My header, main content, and the footer. 
[image]

 It's good. Now, as seen here: 
[image]

 when the browser window is resized, the footer does not cover the content, which is great. So far, so good. Now I scroll down to find my footer, and it's fine; as seen here: 
[image]

 So now let me just resize my browser and uh oh, why is this happening now? 
[image]

 The footer is moving with the browser as it's being resized and covering my main content. I want to keep it below. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's doing basically the right thing. It's covering the content area because your content has no minimum size so it'll be sized by the contents;

```
#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */
```

However, if you do fill it with content, it's doing the  right thing as far as I understand what you're trying to do;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danieljsinclair/znBGR/)

...in that it does *not* cover your content, when you actually have some content